# ServiceNow: accessing widget option schema in mdDialog

Tags: servicenow, angularjs-material, mddialog

I've cloned the OOTB widget-form, named it widget-form-md, and created an additional option schema for hideRelatedLists:

[image]

I have a separate widget that is embedding my cloned widget-form-md and hope to display it via a Material Design modal.  My client script for the modal looks like this:

```
function x ($scope, $location, spUtil, amb, $mdDialog, $http, $window, $rootScope, $timeout){
var c = this;

c.newRequest = function() {
$mdDialog.show({
contentElement: '#hr_request',
parent: angular.element(document.body),
clickOutsideToClose:true
});
spUtil.get("widget-form-md", {
request_name: 'hr_request',
view: 'hr_request',
table: 'x_dnf_federal_hr_e_federal_hr_cases'
}).then(function(response) {
c.hr_request = response;
});
};
}
```

What is the correct syntax to pass in my option schema into the spUtil?  I've tried

```
spUtil.get("widget-form-md", {
request_name: 'hr_request',
hideRelatedLists: true
view: 'hr_request',
table: 'x_dnf_federal_hr_e_federal_hr_cases'
})
```

and

```
spUtil.get("widget-form-md", {
request_name: 'hr_request',
options: {hideRelatedLists:true},
view: 'hr_request',
table: 'x_dnf_federal_hr_e_federal_hr_cases'
})
```

Neither of them worked and I can't seem to find any documentation out there on how to do this.  Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First: Option Schema is used to configure a widget via a table:
https://dxsherpa.com/blogs/widget-options-schema-in-service-portal/

The Solution to the missing parameters, which don't show in the options of the called widgets was here: https://community.servicenow.com/community?id=community_question&sys_id=ea83c365dbd8dbc01dcaf3231f9619d2

> When a widget is called using **spUtil** (client) then the parameters passed are accessed using "**input**".
>
> When a widget is called using **$sp** (server) then the parameters passed are accessed using **"options"**

Since the call the widget with spUtil, we have the data on the server in the input object. Therefor in the **server** of the called widget:

```js
data.requestName = input.request_name;
data.hideRelatedLists = input.hideRelatedLists;
// or the short version, if widget also gets parameters from URL and options:
data.requestName = $sp.getParameter('requestName ') || options.requestName || input.requestName;
```

It's a shame this is not described in the official documentation for it: https://developer.servicenow.com/app.do#!/api_doc?v=london&id=spUtilAPI